# Nginx returns 200 while Apache returns 302 on same PHP application

Tags: nginx, http, redirect, php-fpm

I have a PHP web application that *does* work in my local Apache development environment. However, the same app does *not* work in my production environment with nginx (1.4.6/Ubuntu) and PHP-FPM. When I use [PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in my development environment, the client gets a 302 and is redirected to the appropriate page. However, the same function call serves the client with a 200 response in nginx PHP-FPM.

```
public static function redirect($path = '') { //I call this function with $path='dashboard'
    $location = 'Location: ' . Settings::getConfig()['url'] . $path;
    //var_dump($location); die; // If I leave this line for debugging, this line outputs that $location is a string, and has value 'Location: http://[myDomain]/dashboard'
    header($location); //after this line, nginx sends a 200 back to the client, while Apache (correctly) sends a 302.
}
```

The end result is that clients are not able to login in my production environment. What could be the possible cause of this problem?

Excerpt of my nginx configuration:

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

server {

listen 5001 default_server;
listen [::]:5001 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /var/www/[domain]/public/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name [domain];


location /uploads {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /assets {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm-01.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

My PHP.ini (cli):

```
/[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = -1
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = /tmp
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
```

Other PHP.ini (fpm):

```
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = 17
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 1024
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
track_errors = Off
html_errors = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = On
[SQL]
sql.safe_mode = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent = 1
ibase.max_persistent = -1
ibase.max_links = -1
ibase.timestampformat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat = "%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat = "%H:%M:%S"
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.cache_size = 2000
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.save_path = "/tmp/php_sessions"
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.hash_function = 0
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[mcrypt]
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
```

Comment: What in your PHP code *causes* this `redirect()` function to be executed? You should also always be `exit` or `die`ing after a `Location` header. Otherwise, subsequent PHP code will still execute, so if there's something else in your code that sends a 200 response, that'll do it.

Comment: Upon a successful verification of login credentials, the user is redirected to the application dashboard. 

It's tempting to do a PHP hack to fix this (I've already tried die/exit and it doesn't work), but I've been given this application and been tasked to make it work in nginx as it does in Apache.

Comment: What is sitting in front of nginx?

Comment: Again, what is sitting in front of nginx?

Comment: Sorry for my hours of absence. I'm not a sysadmin and not 100% sure what you're asking, but nginx is not used as a proxy load balancer for Apache etc. My stack consists of Ubuntu 14, nginx 1.4.6/Ubuntu, MySQL and PHP 7.0 with PHP-FPM.

Answer (score 1):

Your function works on nginx/1.13.8 with PHP7.0

nginx configuration  (default)

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

/etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf (default)

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: It should have been clearer in my post, but that `var_dump` is only there for debugging purposes. I've corrected it.

Moreover, apache runs this fine, while my nginx php-fpm stack does not. I wish I could fix the issue by changing the configuration files instead of the code.

Comment: Does nginx give you the Location response header with the 200 OK ?

Comment: No, the location header isn't there. *Can* there even be a location header in HTTP 200?

Comment: So, your redirect function is never called?  Did you check the error logs?   Clear your browser cache?

Comment: Is it the same interface between Apache and PHP as between nginx and  PHP?

Comment: My debugging line `var_dump($location)` *is* called if I leave it in, so I took it for granted that the `header($location)` is also called. I manually inspect the HTTP headers in Burp Suite with Firefox, so the browser isn't the issue. As for the PHP interface, I'm sorry to say I don't know what that is. The Apache environment is a Windows XAMPP installation with all the default settings.

Comment: I've tested your function with nginx/1.13.8 and Apache 2.4.35 on Linux Devuan, and no matter if the header comes before the var_dump or not, I get a 302.  I'll add my nginx default.conf to my answer.